# getting a 405 error - POST is not allowed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, post, fetch

I have this fetch request to get some auth data from my form to the server

```
const registerUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const userName = document.getElementById('username').value
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value
    const confirm = document.getElementById('password-confirm').value

    //Make this better with DOM and css later 
    if (password !== confirm){
        alert('Passworfds dont match')
    }

    const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json())
}
```

The server code to accept this is so far nothing other than this

```
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({ status: 'ok' })
})
```

When i hit the submit button i am getting a POST - 405 - method not allowed error in the console if anyone can please help?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed the Body-Parser?

```
  var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

  app.post("/api/register", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({ status: "ok" });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was slightly foolish and a really simple mistake.

My severs serves my html and the login form was running on live server through VScode on the wrong port. A Simple routing issue I have now solved!